# Create a profile to disable other profiles

Tags: tasker

I have a couple of profiles defined in Tasker that I would only like to enable while traveling abroad. As Tasker cannot recognize the state "traveling abroad", I would like to set this state manually which should then disable all the profiles related to this meta profile "traveling abroad".

I envision this in Tasker:

- Category: Traveling abroad (switch off/on)

  - Profile 1 (switch off/on)
  - Profile 2 (switch off/on)
  - Profile 3 (switch off/on)
  - ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling a profile constitutes as an action so you need to do something in a task only. Tasker supports toggling the status of profiles from a task.

Create a new task and use this action: Tasker → Profile Status

- Name: name of the profile to be toggled
- Set: On/Off/Toggle

When would you or how would you like to run this task is upon you to decide. You can setup a location profile, a time trigger or perhaps, bind the task into a widget (1x1) to toggle all those profiles from a single touch on a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Profile that is always active when it turned on, then use the %pactive variable state in the other profiles so that they are only able to be active when the main profile is.

Comment: Pactive doesn't seem to work in my case 12.24.24/Variables doreplresult: |%PACTIVE| -> |,Home,Cell@Chaturb,|
12.24.24/TD getStatic: Active load: true - ExecuteService
12.24.24/E Profile Status: unknown profile ',Home,Cell@Chaturb,'
12.24.24/E result: stop task (error)
12.24.24/E Error: 1
12.24.24/MacroEdit action finished exeID 1 action no 6 code 159 status: Err next 6